# Silverlight 3 Datagrid. How to access to the current sort properties

Tags: c#, datagrid, silverlight-3.0

I'm using a DataGrid, which datasource is exported to Excel.

I'd like to shape the excel doc according to the current sorting of the DataGrid (which column, and which order).

Anyone knows how to access this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: Use a `PagedCollectionView` as a wrapper for your datasource.

If a sort is used, there will be an item in the `SortDescriptions` property of the `PagedCollectionView`, that will give access to the `PropertyName` on which the grid is sorted, and on the sort direction.